# sonata create entity admin dashboard

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm tryin to use sonata admin bundle.

I have in my dashboard my two entities: user and questionnaire

I have two link for the two entites, add new and list.

But if I click of list for questionnaire, I have the questionnaire list and when I click in user list, I have also questionnaire list (and not user list).

Another problem, when I click to add, I have a good form, but it is related to

```
questionnaireBundle\Entity\questionnaire:0000000037b8f75700000000ca0fce3d
```

why the ":0000000037b8f75700000000ca0fce3d"?

If I fill the form and click create, I have the error :

```
An error has occurred during the creation of item "questionnaireBundle\Entity\avance:000000001c934f6f00000000d6359d04".
```

What have I done?

My questionnaireAdmin:

```
<?php

namespace questionnaireBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class questionnaireAdmin extends Admin {

    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
        $formMapper
                ->add('nom')
                ->add('nbreQuestions')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper) {
        $datagridMapper
                ->add('nom')
                ->add('nbreQuestions')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
        $listMapper
                ->addIdentifier('nom')
                ->add('nbreQuestions')
        ;
    }
}
```

My questionnaire entity:

```
<?php

namespace questionnaireBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * questionnaire
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class questionnaire {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbreQuestions", type="integer")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Veuillez entrer un nombre de questions.")
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    private $nbreQuestions;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return questionnaire
     */
    public function setNom($nom) {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom() {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set nbreQuestions
     *
     * @param integer $nbreQuestions
     * @return questionnaire
     */
    public function setNbreQuestions($nbreQuestions) {
        $this->nbreQuestions = $nbreQuestions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nbreQuestions
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNbreQuestions() {
        return $this->nbreQuestions;
    }

}
```

My config:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: @UserBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
    - { resource: @questionnaireBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }
```

My admin user service:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.user:
        class: UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "User" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - UserBundle\Entity\User
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [UserBundle]]
```

My admin questionnaire service:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.questionnaire:
        class: questionnaireBundle\Admin\questionnaireAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "questionnaire" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - questionnaireBundle\Entity\questionnaire
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [questionnaireBundle]]
```

my confi.yml:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        # Your other blocks
```

Comment: I have added some code, if you need more, you can say

Answer (score 2):

To prevent sonata from showing 0000000037b8f75700000000ca0fce3d you need to add toString methode to your entities.
For the problem of the dashboard links can you show me the dashboard configuration in your config.yml i think that you reffer to the same service in the configuration. 
Finaly if  Sonata return an errors mesasge you have to check your logic , i mean that you have to check your Assert and check the object after the form submit event.

Comment: Here is the error image: http://s29.postimg.org/v50z3msqf/Sans_titre1.png

I have add the function:     public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->nom;
    } 

in my questionnaire entity, it will work and erase the top messge, but the error at the bottom stay

Comment: ToString methode must be like this :

public function __tostring() {       
        return $this->nom;

    }

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my message jsut before you sent. I have added the config.yml editing my question a the top.

Comment: im talking about the dashboard configuration under sonata admin in config.yml. Try to add those lines in your user admin
 protected $baseRouteName = 'sonata_admin_user';
  protected $baseRoutePattern = 'admin/user';

Comment: I don't have another one in the app/config/config.yml file.

I have tried to change these variables, but it doesn't have any effect. 

my path is: http://localhost/questionnaire/web/app_dev.php/admin/your_name/create 

The variables was:     protected $baseRouteName= 'your_name';

    protected $baseRoutePattern= 'your_name';

Comment: I have tried this, if I comment     - { resource: @questionnaireBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml } OF CONFIG.YML and all the admin.yml (of the questionnaire), il will work only with the user, but it show me the user entity with all the informations. Why when I have the two at the same time it doesn't work?